# In a string that is between 2 characters, find text after last delimiter

Tags: regex

I need to find all `_` in a string, but only if the whole string is between `{` and `}`. Also, the string we need to check must come after the last delimiter: `,`.

An example (sorry for the "messy" example):

```
{some_text_1,some_text_1_more,some_text_1_more_more,0_1_2}INTERSECT{some_text_2,some_text_2_more,some_text_2_more_more,text,abc_efg_hijk}
```

The strings I need to go over are:
`0_1_2` and `abc_efg_hijk`. I need to catch their `_`.

The reason for this is that I want to replace `_` with a different delimiter as this one is causing issue. I will use `regexp_replace` after finding the correct regex.

For now I only managed to capture the strings between `{` and `}` using the following regex, but I failed to get `_` after the last iteration of `,`:

`(?<=\{)(.*?)(?=\})`

Comment: Which programming language is this? Also why insist on using regex...?

Comment: I don't know what issue you're talking about but what about fixing the "issue" in the first place instead...? Also what's wrong with replacing all underscores then change them back later after getting rid of whatever "issue" there is?

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: @user202729 I need to permanently change ```_``` to something else, I cant change it temporarily. If there are other solution you have in mind then I am open to hear, I just thought of using Regex as I my DB is Postgres.

Comment: @anubhava I am going to run this on Postgres, so I am not sure but I think it is PHP>7.3?  Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is supported and you don't need to check for the opening `{` try e.g.

```
_(?=[^,}{]*})
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uVe7wy/1)

It looks if there is a closing `}` ahead with [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) of [`[^,}{]`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) in between.